# Post approval action on Knowledge articles

Tags: chatter, approval-process, knowledge, articles, post

I have a business requirement as follows:

When a knowledge article gets approved, the article title, subject and article link to be posted on chatter and will be available to specific group(s).

I already have an approval process which is updating an article as 'Published' status after final approval action. I want to leverage this same approval process with this additional action.

I know that we cannot define trigger on Knowledge article types.

Any feedback and help is appreciated to implement this functionality. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this functionality through Process builder.

Defined the criteria for 'Published' Knowledge article and in the immediate action chosen 'Post to Chatter'.